# How to send this make a curl request from this c# code which uses RestSharp

Tags: c#, curl

I cannot make a curl request the same way as the code is downloading the file in Rest Sharp. It either shows permission denied or does not allow it. What would be the proper way of making a Curl request from this:

```
var client = new RestClient(URL);
var request = new RestRequest("&amp;username=user&amp;password=pass", Method.GET);
var queryResult = client.Execute(request);
client.DownloadData(request).SaveAs(C://file.xml);
```

URL is https

Comment: `&amp;` should be `&`

Comment: The above code works, I just want to know how I would turn that to a curl request what would I need to pass in: curl -L --output C:// URL

Comment: Perform your curl request as previously found failing, except with the change I stated. Restsharp 'fixes' html string for you, curl does not.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand this: Perform your curl request as previously found failing. Can you show me an example?

Comment: You stated you can't do the request in curl because it returns as permission denied. That is because your string is incorrect that gives the username and password.

Comment: I'm adding it to the curl request as URL&amp;username=user&amp;password=pass

Comment: Now change the url as directed in my first comment and try again. This is simply a typographical error where curl doesn't fix the url for you.

Comment: Still doesn't work with taking out the &amp

Comment: `&amp;` should be `&` so just remove amp; and leave the &

Comment: Yes this is what I have done. Should I be using different arguments for https?